# How to convert word document with mathml content to HTML

Tags: html, xml, vba, ms-word, mathml

**My objective** is to convert word document to HTML and if equation presents in a document, then it must be converted into mathml before saving it as HTML.

So I converted all the equation into mathml using mathtype. Now, word document will have mathml content too.

If I save it as "web page filtered" document, I get it as HTML but mathml tags are getting converted to entity.

**For example:**

sample.docx

```
<mrow>&#456;</mrow>
```

is converted to

```
&lt;mrow&gt; &amp;&#67;456;&lt;/mrow&gt;
```

**EXPECTATION**

I need to convert this document into HTML but if mathml contents present, then that mathml content alone shouldn't be converted into HTML. What would be the solution for this?

I need something like, XML file `<![CDATA[ unparsed char ]]>` . In word file, how can I shield mathml content not to be converted?

Comment: IIRC, MathType adds a type of export they call "Math Page", which creates HTML with MathML (and a call to MathJax). See e.g. http://dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/tsn/tsn148.htm

Comment: @Peter Krautzberger - Thank you so much! This is what I expected.